# Change Object Attribute Variable On Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < account.feed.data.length; i++) { 
  const rendernew = Object.assign(render ,{account_post_VARIABLE I HERE: `${account.feed.data[i].id}`});
}
```

I would like to make it so once it loops is changes the attribute so it adds a new line instead of re writing the value of the attribute. Any ideas, Thanks!!! :)

Expected Output:

```
{
  account_post_0: "1234"
  account_post_1: "5678"
  account_post_2: "9012"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further, with an example input and desired output?

Comment: [**Computed Property Names**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). ``{["account_post_"+i]: `${account.feed.data[i].id}`}``

Comment: Ok thanks I will try

Comment: @iNcizzle Had a mistake, edited the code in the previous comment.

Comment: @TylerRoper Worked Perfectyly thanks alot :)

Comment: Not a problem. Not sure why I elected to combine concatenation and template literals, but I can't edit that comment now. In any event, you might prefer something like this instead: ``{[`account_post_${i}`]: `${account.feed.data[i].id}`}``

Comment: may I ask why you don't use array?

Comment: @appleapple I need to pass the values of these attributes to pug

Comment: @iNcizzle I don't know it, but I believe it would support array. otherwise it's a flawed framework and I would not use it.

Comment: @appleapple OP's expected output doesn't seem to align with their code. It's a templating engine, thus it makes sense it would require key/value pairs, like `account_post_0: "123", account_post_1: "456"`, etc. Replace any instance of `{account_post_0}` with `"123"`, so on and so forth.

Comment: @TylerRoper I would say then what should change is the template.

Comment: and a quick search seems it does have a [each](https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html#prefixed-each-syntax)

Comment: Sure, however I think without more detail, to start discussing the proper usage of an unfamiliar framework (*"otherwise it's flawed and I would not use it"*) when we've seen exactly one `for` loop seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @TylerRoper well, just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as assign each attribute in a loop.

```js
let account={feed:{data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(x=>({id:x}))}}

let obj={};
for (let i = 0; i < account.feed.data.length; i++) { 
  obj[`account_post_${i}`] = `${account.feed.data[i].id}`
}

console.log(obj)
```